# Latex Hyperref with Pagenumber

Tags: latex

i want to use hyperref in my latex document to link to labels
and i want to show the page number of the label. 
so for example:

```
\label{subsubsec:foo}
\hyperref[subsubsec:foo]{See foo on page ???}
```

How can i get the page number of the label?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! (La)TeX-related questions are better asked at http://tex.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that hypperef is only used to create hyperlink in PDF document (see https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Hyperlinks ).
In order to get the page number of a label, use the \pageref command and provide it the name of the label as first argument (see https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Labels_and_Cross-referencing ).

Your code should be:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
[...]
\label{subsubsec:foo}
[...]
See foo on page \pageref{subsubsec:foo}
```

As a consequence of the inclusion of the hypperef package, hyperlinks will be present in the generated PDF document.